# Filtering on orders table by sub category using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem and need help.

I use wpf and entity framework with data sources, and I have dragged a listview onto the form. It is display all orders at the moment, but I only want to select the "drinks" from orders. So based on the products table with the categoryID i want to filter what will be displayed in the listview. I tried filtering on collections and using LINQ to make a query for it.

Here's my db diagram: https://i.ibb.co/5kx1rzp/IMG-20190116-WA0000.jpg

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What did you try still so far? No one can help you without proper information. Image is also blurred.

Comment: I don't see 'drinks' in your tables.  Please show your linq query.  Please show the XAML binding.